# User Login Session Timeout Logout With OOP Login/Register System

Tags: php, oop, session

I am using an **OOP** login/register system and I want to apply a session timeout, I've looked at alot of tutorials and all of them explain how to go about it using a normal login/register system only. here are some of my codes:

**init.php**

```
session_start();
 $GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'host'      =>  '127.0.0.1',
        'username'  =>  'root',
        'password'  =>  '',
        'db'        =>  'database'   
    ),

    'remember'  =>  array(
        'cookie_name'   =>  'hash',
        'cookie_expiry' =>  '604800'
    ),

    'session'   =>  array(
        'session_name'  =>  'user',
        'token_name'    =>  'token'
    )
);
```

**Below are my classes that deal with logging in**

**Session.php**

```
class Session {
public static function exists($name){
    return (isset($_SESSION[$name])) ? true : false;
}

public static function put($name, $value){
    return $_SESSION[$name] = $value;
}

public static function get($name){
    return $_SESSION[$name];
}

public static function delete($name){
    if(self::exists($name)){
        unset($_SESSION[$name]);
    }
}

public static function flash($name, $string = ''){
    if(self::exists($name)){
        $session = self::get($name);
        return $session;
    }else{
        self::put($name, $string);
    }
}
```

}

**User.php**

```
class User{
private $_db,
        $_data,
        $_sessionName,
        $_isLoggedIn;


public function __construct($user = null) {
    $this->_db = DB::getInstance();

    $this->_sessionName = Config::get('session/session_name');

    if(!$user){
        if(Session::exists($this->_sessionName)){
            $user = Session::get($this->_sessionName);

            if($this->find($user)){
                $this->_isLoggedIn = true;
            }else{
                //process logout
            }
        }    
    }else{
        $this->find($user);
    }
}

public function user_password($password = null){
    if($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)){
        return true;
    }
}


public function find($user = null){
    if($user){
        $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'user_id' : 'username';
        $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));
        if($data->count()){
           $this->_data = $data->first();
            return true; 
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function login($username = null, $password = null){
    $user = $this->find($username);

    if($user){
        if($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)){
            //This palce is important, change the user_id to the name of the users' table primary key
            Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->user_id);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function hasPermission($key){
    $group = $this->_db->get('groups', array('id', '=', $this->data()->group));

    if($group->count()){
        $permissions = json_decode($group->first()->permissions, true);

        if($permissions[$key] == true){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function logout(){
    Session::delete($this->_sessionName);
}

public function data(){
    return $this->_data;
}

public function isLoggedIn(){
    return $this->_isLoggedIn;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can add a **`$_SESSION['timeOfLogin'] = time();`** if the login succeeds.

While performing any task you can check if the login is still valid to go on by sending  **`$_SESSION['timeOfLogin']`** to the following function

```
 public function sessionIsValid($timeOfLogin){
    //Lets say expiry is 1 day
    $expiryTime=24*60*60; 
    //Get the current time
    $currentTime = time();
   // How much time user has spent
    $timeDifference = $currentTime - timeOfLogin;
   //If time spent is less than expiry then it is good to go
    if($timeDifference < $expiryTime)
     return true;
    else
     return false;

    }
```